# How to add a second feature to a countvectorized feature using sklearn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have 3 columns in my data set:

**Review**: A product review

**Type**: A category or product type

**Cost**: How much the product cost

This is a multiclass problem, with Type as the target variable. There are 64 different Types of products in this dataset.

**Review** and **Cost** are my two features.

I've split the data into 4 sets with the **Type** variable removed:

```
X = data.drop('type', axis = 1)
y = data.type
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)
```

For **Review**, I am using the following to vectorize it:

```
vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words = stop)
X_train_dtm = vect.fit_transform(X_train.review)
```

Here's where I am stuck!

In order to run the model I need to have both my features in the training set, however, since X_train_dtm is a sparse matrix, I am unsure as to how I concatenate my pandas series **Cost** feature to that sparse matrix.  Since the data is already numerical for the **Cost**, I don't think that I need to transform it, which is why I have not used something like "FeatureUnion" which combines 2 transformed features.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Example data:

```
| Review           | Cost        | Type         |
|:-----------------|------------:|:------------:|
| This is a review |        200  |     Toy     
| This is a review |        100  |     Toy    
| This is a review |        800  |  Electronics     
| This is a review |         35  |     Home
```

**Update**

After applying tarashypka's solution I was able to rid add the second feature to the X_train_dtm. However, I am getting an error when attempting to run the same on the test set:

from scipy.sparse import hstack

```
vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words = stop)
X_train_dtm = vect.fit_transform(X_train.review)
prices = X_train.prices.values[:,None]
X_train_dtm = hstack((X_train_dtm, prices))

#Works perfectly for the training set above
#But when I run with test set I get the following error
X_test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test)
prices_test = X_test.prices.values[:,None]
X_test_dtm = hstack((X_test_dtm, prices_test))

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-b2861d63b847>", line 8, in <module>
    X_test_dtm = hstack((X_test_dtm, points_test))

  File "C:\Users\k\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 464, in hstack
    return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\Users\k\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 581, in bmat
    'row dimensions' % i)

ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions
```

Comment: Can you upload your data ?

Comment: @sera I added some example data, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `CountVectorizer`, in your case `X_train_dtm`, is of type `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`. If you don't want to convert it to the numpy array, then `scipy.sparse.hstack` is the way to add another column

```
>> from scipy.sparse import hstack
>> prices = X_train['Cost'].values[:, None]
>> X_train_dtm = hstack((X_train_dtm, prices))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am getting the following error:
ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions

Comment: Yes, it's because data and X_train_dtm have different number of rows, since second is the result of splitting the first one. I updated the answer, check it now.

Comment: thank you! This worked, however I encountered the same block error when attempting to make the hstack on the test set. I've updated the original question.

Comment: @NegativeCorrelation You need to call `fit_transform` instead of `transform` (as you did for the train set), since the second one returns `None`.

Comment: Doing so still results in the same issue:

ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions

Comment: @NegativeCorrelation Make sure that your code for test set is the same as for train set, then it should work accordingly. For example, you have  `vect.transform(X_test)` instead of `vect.fit_transform(X_test.review)` in yours updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FeatureUnion`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) to hstack things for you. The [example on heterogeneous data](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html) is quite like your problem.